# How to reinitialize Html Builder in yajra datatable - laravel controller

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I am using yjra datatable and html builder plugin. i want to show two datatable in one view. i am getting error like can not reinitialize

Controller :

```
        public function edit($id ,Builder $builder){
        
        $this->htmlBuilder->ajax(route('backend.ajax.my_peoples', ['project_id'=> $project->project_id,'request' => 'ajax_listing']));
                $people_html = $this->htmlBuilder->columns([
                    ['data' => 'project_person_role', 'name' => 'project_person_role', 'title' => 'Person Role'],
                    ['data' => 'project_person_sort', 'name' => 'project_person_sort', 'title' => 'Sort'],
                    ['data' => 'project_person_status', 'name' => 'project_person_status', 'title' => 'Status'],
                    ['data' => 'action', 'name' => 'action', 'title' => 'Action', 'orderable' => false, 'searchable' => false, 'width' => '10%'],
                ]);
    
    $this->htmlBuilder->ajax(route('backend.ajax.my_consultants', ['project_id'=> $project->project_id,'request' => 'ajax_listing']));
            $dt_html = $this->htmlBuilder->columns([
                ['data' => 'project_consultant_role', 'name' => 'project_consultant_role', 'title' => 'Consultant Role'],
                ['data' => 'project_consultant_sort', 'name' => 'project_consultant_sort', 'title' => 'Sort'],
                ['data' => 'project_consultant_status', 'name' => 'project_consultant_status', 'title' => 'Status'],
                ['data' => 'action', 'name' => 'action', 'title' => 'Action', 'width' => '5%', 'orderable' => false, 'searchable' => false]
            ]);

return view('backend.projects.projects')->with([
            'view_type' => 'edit',
            'view_title' => 'Update',
      
            'cslt_html' => $dt_html,
            'people_html' => $people_html
        ]);
        
        }
```